# Is there any method to validate a query in the BigQuery api

Tags: google-api, google-bigquery, google-api-php-client

I'm using [Google APIs Client Library for php](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client), and I'd like to be able to validate a query before send it to execution. Are there any method in the [Google BigQuery  API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/) to validate a query (**Get the text in the red box**).

I couldn't find it. I was reading this section https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/query

[image: BigQuery validator]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Setting the [`dryRun`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/query#dryRun) parameter to true on a `jobs.query` request should allow you to validate a query.  Dry run queries don't catch all errors, but they can catch quite a few.  The query validator in the web UI uses dry run queries to provide real-time errors as shown in your screenshot.

Docs for the `dryRun` parameter:

> [Optional] If set, don't actually run this job. A valid query will return a mostly empty response with some processing statistics, while an invalid query will return the same error it would if it wasn't a dry run.

Comment: Thanks for the help, are there a way to get the estimated amount of data processed that the validator show when the query is correct, e.g:  `Valid: This query will process 501.81 MB when run.`

Comment: Yep, this information is also returned when you call jobs.query with the dryRun flag.